# How can I use JSON to send Django data over websockets?

Tags: javascript, json, django

I am developing a django application that sends data over websockets

I am putting the data into a java object that is converted to JSON and then parsed at the other end

My code is

```
chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e)
    const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
};

document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').onclick = function(e) {
    const messageInputDom = document.querySelector('#chat-message-input');
    const message = messageInputDom.value;
    var messageObject = {
        'username': username,
        'message': message,
        'test': 'abc',
        }
    console.log(messageObject)
    chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify(messageObject));
};
```

The messageObject appears to be well formed

```
{username: "jeff", message: "qwerty", test: "abc"}
```

but the output in the *onmessage* function only shows

```
MessageEvent {isTrusted: true, data: "{"message": "qwerty"}", origin: "ws://192.168.1.138:8000", lastEventId: "", source: null, …}
```

Where have my other data gone?

Comment: use `JSON.stringify(message)`

Comment: Sorry That doesn't work. What about the other data in the messageObject?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be that the django code that I use requires that the data be transferred in a variable named *message*. This is a typical case of *... a little knowledge ...*

I am familiar with Python, but new to javascript. Thus, when I encountered a problem, I assumed the problem was in my javascript and did not look farther.

**consumers.py**

```
...
# Receive message from WebSocket
async def receive(self, text_data):
    text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
    message = text_data_json['message']
...
# Receive message from room group
async def chat_message(self, event):
    message = event['message']
...
```

The following code solved the problem:

```
chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
    const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    messageObject = data.message
    username = messageObject.username
    text = messageObject.text
};

document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').onclick = function(e) {
    const messageInputDom = document.querySelector('#chat-message-input');
    const text = messageInputDom.value;
    var messageObject = {
        'message': {'username': username, 'text': text, 'test': 'abc'},
        }
    chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify(messageObject));
};
```